# Broken pipe while using SSH

Tags: ssh

One of my server computers shows a "broken pipe" message while I'm using SSH after 10 minutes even though I execute simulation program programmed with python3.5.

I tried

1. Editing `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` files
2. Ignoring power-save mode
3. Re-installing Ubuntu 16.04
4. Using tmux for the simulation.

In addition, after the disconnection between the server and local client, I tried tmux attach command but it didn't work.

The most weird thing is only the one server shows this symptom. Other server works well without any broken pipe message.

What should I do?

Comment: you should check ssh configuration file. there are ClientAliveInterval property and ServerAliveInterval that should help here. Compare /etc/ssh/ssh_config file with server that works this should give you an idea :) May be is missing ServerAliveInterval

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the servers settings, idle connections may be dropped.

To prevent this from the client side, use `ssh` option `ServerAliveInterval`.

Use this in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host xyz
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

or using command line option `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=120 ...`

---

Alternatively, you can change the setting from the server side in `ssdh_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval ...
```